# List child items of SharePoint document sub folder

Tags: sharepoint, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to use Microsoft Graph to list and download files in SharePoint. I'm using direct http not any library. My problem is that I cannot list child items of subfolders found in SharePoint libraries.

I start the process by using this call to obtain a list of drive Ids:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/host.sharepoint.com/drives
```

("host" is actually different for my site)

Let's say a driveId is "ABCDEF".  I then use this call to obtain a list of files within the SharePoint drive:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/host.sharepoint.com/drives/ABCDEF/root/children
```

This yields for each file a fileId and filename. If my document library has a subfolder created, I can differentiate between files and folders by looking for the item "folder". The id of the subfolder looks similar to those of files. Let's say the folder Id is "XYZ".

Now I want to obtain a list of child items for the sub folder. I use this call:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/host.sharepoint.com/drive/items/XYZ/children
```

Unfortunately this results in http error 404 with the message "The resource could not be found". I have tried variations of this url, such as drives/XYZ/root/children but nothing works.

Could someone provide me with the correct url to obtain a list of files from within a SharePoint library
subfolder?

Comment: Hi did you have a chance to check my answer?

Comment: Sorry to be late in getting back - yes, that works great, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the default drive `host.sharepoint.com/drive/` is different from `host.sharepoint.com/drives/ABCDEF`.

`XYZ` is under `ABCDEF` rather than the default drive.

Use `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/host.sharepoint.com/drives/ABCDEF/items/XYZ/children` should resolve this issue.